# Compare values and return based on condition from the result sql

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables: tests and test_status

tests:

```
--------------------
|  id  |  name     |
--------------------
|  1   |  Test 1   |
|  2   |  Test 2   |
|  3   |  Test 3   |
|  4   |  Test 1   |
|  5   |  Test 2   |
--------------------
```

test_status:

```
------------------------------------------
|  id  |  test_id  |  run_id  |  status  |
------------------------------------------
|  1   |  1        |  1       |  PASS    |
|  2   |  2        |  1       |  PASS    |
|  3   |  3        |  1       |  FAIL    |
|  4   |  4        |  2       |  FAIL    |
|  5   |  5        |  2       |  PASS    |
------------------------------------------
```

I want to retrieve the test names which are passed on the first run and failed on the second run. So in this case it has to display the **Test1**. My SQL query knowledge is very novice and hence seeking your help.

Comment: Do you only have two runs? Or will there be more runs and this has to be a more general solution?

Comment: @wolfgangwalther: Yeah thats a good question. I'll be having more than 2 runs, so the general solution would be more better. Say for an example, I want the information for last n runs.

Comment: You probably need to tell us more about the general approach then: Do you want to find tests, that pass in run N and fail in run N+1 or something like that?

Comment: or max run_id fail but max run_id -1 = pass

Comment: @ah_hau: yes you are correct, I need as you mentioned.

Comment: @wolfgangwalther: I need as suggested by ah_hau

Comment: And it would probably make things easier, if you changed your table data a little bit. I would suggest to have unique rows in `tests` and reference those in `test_status`. Otherwise you don't need that extra table.
So the values of column `test_id` would become `1 2 3 1 2` right now.

Comment: @wolfgangwalther: I agree, but unfortunately the data is generated by 3rd party app where I can't change the schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe, you should change `tests` so that it has one entry per test:

```
create table tests (
   id    integer     primary key,
   name  varchar(10)
);
```

You would then fill it like so

```
insert into tests values (1, 'Test 1');
insert into tests values (2, 'Test 2');
insert into tests values (3, 'Test 3');
```

The table `test_status` almost stays the same, except that `test_id` changes according to the "minimized" `test` table:

```
create table test_status (
  id      integer primary key,
  test_id integer references tests,
  run_id  integer,
  status  varchar(4)
);
```

And it is filled like so:

```
insert into test_status values (1, 1, 1, 'PASS');
insert into test_status values (2, 2, 1, 'PASS');
insert into test_status values (3, 3, 1, 'FAIL');
insert into test_status values (4, 1, 2, 'FAIL');
insert into test_status values (5, 2, 2, 'PASS');
```

Then, with the following query, you find your desired record:

```
select
  test.name
from
  tests test                                             join
  test_status first_run  on test.id = first_run.test_id  join
  test_status second_run on test.id = second_run.test_id
where
  first_run.status  = 'PASS' and
  second_run.status = 'FAIL' and
  first_run.run_id  = 1      and
  second_run.run_id = 2;
```

**EDIT** So, from the question's comment, I take it you want actually the tests where the n<sup>th</sup> test passes, but the (n+1)<sup>th</sup> fails. In that case, you change the query to

```
select
  test.name
from
  tests test                                             join
  test_status first_run  on test.id = first_run.test_id  join
  test_status second_run on test.id = second_run.test_id
where
  first_run.status  = 'PASS' and
  second_run.status = 'FAIL' and
  first_run.run_id  = second_run.run_id - 1 -- Change HERE!
;
```

**EDIT II** So, you are stuck with a vendor's idea of the ERD. In this case, you need to adapt a bit:

```
create table tests (
   id    integer     primary key,
   name  varchar(10)
);


insert into tests values (1, 'Test 1');
insert into tests values (2, 'Test 2');
insert into tests values (3, 'Test 3');
insert into tests values (4, 'Test 1');
insert into tests values (5, 'Test 2');

create table test_status (
  id      integer primary key,
  test_id integer references tests,
  run_id  integer,
  status  varchar(4)
);

insert into test_status values (1, 1, 1, 'PASS');
insert into test_status values (2, 2, 1, 'PASS');
insert into test_status values (3, 3, 1, 'FAIL');
insert into test_status values (4, 4, 2, 'FAIL');
insert into test_status values (5, 5, 2, 'PASS');
```

The query becomes a bit more clumsy

```
select
  test_1.name
from
  tests       test_1                                  join
  tests       test_2  on test_1.name = test_2.name    join
  test_status run_1   on test_1.id   = run_1.test_id join
  test_status run_2   on test_2.id   = run_2.test_id
where
  run_1.status = 'PASS' and
  run_2.status = 'FAIL' and
  run_1.run_id = run_2.run_id - 1;
```

The same queries as [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/4c434/2)

Comment: Unfortunately, the data is generated by 3rd party app where I don't have an access to change the schema.

Comment: I get the wrong result when I tried to add the new run, with slightly a different data. Ex: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/5bf613/1. I was expecting to return 0, but it returns Test 1. I guess it always takes 1st and 2nd test runs.

Comment: It is working fine with a small change in Where clause. Instead of run_1.run_id = run_2.run_id - 1, I made as run_1.run_id = 2 and run_2.run_id = 3;. The 2 and 3 can be handled with another select query with max of id. Thanks for your help buddy.

Answer (score 0):

```
select tests.name from tests 
inner join test_status maxRun on tests.id = maxRun.test_id
inner join test_status maxRun_1 on tests.id = maxRun_1.test_id
where maxRun.run_id = (select max(run_id) from test_status max where tests.id = max.test_id)
and maxRun_1.run_id = (select max(run_id) -1 from test_status max where tests.id = max.test_id)
and maxRun.status = 'FAIL'
and maxRun_1.status = 'PASS'
```

you may try it out, not sure it work or not, if you can create your test data in fiddle, I can help to test out the query.